# IO Monad#map Function

Tags: scala, monads

Looking at the IO Monad from [Functional Programming in Scala](http://www.manning.com/bjarnason/), I see the following code:

**I0.scala**

`def ReadLine: IO[String] = IO { readLine }`

**I0Test.scala**

```
val readInt = ReadLine.map(_.toInt)
val result: Int = readInt * readInt
```

When I run the above line in one of my ScalaTests, the console waits for me to enter 2 inputs.

After entering two numbers, the 2 inputs' product is stored in `result`. When calling `ReadLine.map(_.toInt)`, does the `map` result in a call to `run` that convert its output to an `Int`?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this code:

```
scala> def ReadLine: Option[String] = Some(readLine)
ReadLine: Option[String]

scala> val readInt = ReadLine.map(_.toInt)
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "asd"
```

In this primitive example the `readline` is eagerly evaluated and throws an error. Another thing to note that `readInt` here is a variable, not a function.

In your example I believe (no code provided but "according to the book") a new monad is created when `map` is called, and result of `map` is not yet evaluated. This also makes  `readInt` a type of function that takes no args and can be applied by simply calling it, which happens when you do `readInt * readInt` and that's why you get 2 input prompts.